# PhpOffice\PhpWord - TemplateProcessor add List

Tags: php, phpoffice

I'm using using PhpOffice library. Is there any option how to replace Variable in docx file with ordered list?

With templateProcessor method setComplexValue I can add text with code

```
$title = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun();
$title->addText('This title has been set ', array('bold' => true, 'italic' => true, 'color' => 'blue'));
$title->addText('dynamically', array('bold' => true, 'italic' => true, 'color' => 'red', 'underline' => 'single'));
$templateProcessor->setComplexBlock('title', $title);
```

So I tried this code for new List but it's not working.

```
$list = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\ListItem();
$list->addListItem('List item 1');
$list->addListItem('List item 2');
$templateProcessor->setComplexValue('list', $list);
```

Any Ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

maybe someone'll find this useful.

Doc file (template) should be:

```
    ${block}
        ${item} <---- in MS Word, make this line a List Item
    ${/block}
```

PHP should be something like this:

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($YOUR_LIST_ITEMS);$i++) {
        $replacements[]= array('item' => $YOUR_LIST_ITEMS[$i]);
    }
    $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block', 0, true, false, $replacements);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution for this and I have done it with text and line breaks. This solution is ok for my needs. Hope somebody shares a solution for the list too.

```
$list = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun();
$list->addText('* List item 1');
$list->addTextBreak(1);                
$list->addText('* List item 2');
$list->addTextBreak(1);
$templateProcessor->setComplexValue('list', $list);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use setComplexBlock instead